# Can I implement a ViewLocator with KnockoutJS?

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

Does KnockoutJS provide some way to implement a ViewLocator?

A ViewLocator is similar to a component binding but the difference is that it binds to a ViewModel object and
automatically figures out the correct View to instantiate and bind.

For example i want to write this

```
<div data-bind="component: $data"></div>
```

or

```
<div data-bind="component: $data.DetailsViewModel"></div>
```

or

```
<div data-bind="viewLocator: $data.DetailsViewModel"></div>
```

and i want it to find using a naming convention and create the DetailsView.html and bind it to the data bound DetailsViewModel observable.

Note that **I do not want to have to specify a component name and without having to manually register components**!

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "find and create the DetailsView.html"? Where should it find it?

Comment: Locate the template using some convention

Comment: It's possible, if the right amount of effort is put into it. IMO this question requires too much effort for being suitable on SO. Upon googling 'viewLocator' I suspect you come from a Durandal background, and as such would suggest as a first step to look at how they implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by means of a custom component loader.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html

And inject the full view model through a parameter that is used by a custom createViewModel to expose it to the view.

```
<div data-bind='component: {
    name: "DetailsView",
    params: { injectModel: DetailsViewModel}
}'></div>
```

Comment: I do not want to to specify the name explicitly. I want it to happen through code using a naming convention

Comment: i also dont want to have to register anything. My naming convention is able to automatically lookup a component.

Comment: What is the difference of writing "DatailsView" w.r.t. DetailsViewModel? You are still fixing the "name" of the component, in the first way saying it explicitly in the second one you want a way to remove "Model" from the variable name. There is no practical difference.

Comment: You do not have to register them. With custom loaders you can avoid it. The default one ask you to register them, your can just follow a convention to find the template.